# which layer of MVC does spring configuration file reside?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am fairly new to Spring. Can anyone tell me which layer of MVC does spring configuration file reside. As per definition of M, V and C, I think it should be controller layer but I don't know if it is right.

Comment: As the name suggests it is used to configure how your application should work and what what your application depends on. Its a seperate configuration file that is used your MVC architechture

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really an answer but it is too long for a comment.

I think it would be unhelpful to think of MVC as too rigid.  Historically it came forth (MUCH earlier than most people know) as a separation of concerns.  This paradigm predates the web by at least 10 years.

When end user devices started having enough brains to do useful work it became obvious that just because your PC (not quite so dumb terminal) could store program code it was not the right place from which to make database calls and ship results sets.  One of the first *client-server* applications I ever saw had as just one of its growing pains the brilliant idea to download all the possible customers into a pick list on a diskless unix workstation.  Unfortunately that customer list was over 100,000 entries.  Needless to say that didn't work well.

The very first separation of concerns I know of was an IBM philosophy dating to the mid-1980.  Each piece of the application in a 2 or 3 tier model was split into distinct services that could be compartmentalized.  They were:

1. Presentation Service (aka View)
2. Application Service (general utility functions)
3. Application Logic (aka Domain; aka Controller)
4. Data Manipulator / Data State Controller (aka Model)

It is really amazing that there are so few new ideas under the sun.  The names change.  The concepts don't.  The main thing missing from the above list is the SERVICE interface (aka Spring @Service).  They had not delineated clear entry points to the Application Logic yet.  Also Application Service lost its focus in being called out and just slunk back into the UTIL folder where it probably belongs.

As to your question, by default @Configuration stuff is Controller of MVC.  Not because the other legs can stand on their own, they can't.  But because it obviously isn't a Model or a View.

You would probably benefit from reading about Spring PRE Spring Boot.  Personally I really dislike Spring Boot.  It is a bridge too far IMO in giving up control of the environment.

There are really fascinating (well to me at least) things to know about multiple contexts and parent child relationships.  This is more than just a completely academic exercise if you properly structure your Model and Controller stuff separately from your View stuff.

I am also fond of using Spring Profiles to swap out Oracle and H2 so tests can complete within the normal human lifespan.  Not to mention being repeatable, which direct database access almost certainly is not.